# Is there a query to get a resultset

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'matches' containing data something like this:

```
team1   team2   result_team_1   result_team_2
TEAM1   TEAM2   2               9
TEAM3   TEAM4   0               0
```

Is there a way (query, view, etc.) to get a result-set like

```
1 team2 9 2 3
2 team1 2 9 0
3 team3 0 0 1
4 team4 0 0 1
```

Like a typical result table, known in each sport.

Comment: Explain the wanted result. Why does team2 have the values 9, 2, 3?

Comment: win, draw, lose

Comment: Win = 3, lose = 0, draw = 1? So why win = 3 and not 2?

Comment: I thought 2 9 meant 2 goals vs. 9 goals. Now 9 is wins...

Comment: I think that 2-9 are goals, I'm about 5th column with values 3 0 1 1.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: It looks like a football/soccer league table to me, obviously because of the point scheme. But if so, team1 should be at the bottom because they lost (and with 0 point), isn't it?

Comment: @tcadidot0 yeah, OP did say "like", obviously they meant that very loosely :-). The correct table for those results is shown below.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas 3 points for a win, 1 for a draw, 0 for a loss.

Comment: @Nick . . . Although you have a reasonable interpretation of the "3", I'm voting to close because I think the question is incomplete and unclear without an explanation of the last column.

Comment: @streetmaster86 you need to explain how the last column is derived...

Comment: @GordonLinoff coming from a country that plays soccer it's not unclear to me but that's fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

This query will run on MySQL 5.x. It uses MySQL variables to emulate the `ROW_NUMBER` function. If you are using MySQL 8+ I would recommend the second query as variables are deprecated in MySQL 8 and may be removed in future versions.

```
SELECT *,
       @rank := @rank + 1 AS position
FROM (
  SELECT team, 
         SUM(points) AS points, 
         SUM(goals_for) AS goals_for, 
         SUM(goals_against) AS goals_against
  FROM (
    SELECT team1 AS team,
           CASE WHEN m.result_team_1 > m.result_team_2 THEN 3
                WHEN m.result_team_1 = m.result_team_2 THEN 1
                ELSE 0 END AS points,
           m.result_team_1 AS goals_for,
           m.result_team_2 AS goals_against
    FROM matches m
    UNION ALL
    SELECT team2 AS team,
           CASE WHEN m.result_team_2 > m.result_team_1 THEN 3
                WHEN m.result_team_2 = m.result_team_1 THEN 1
                ELSE 0 END AS points,
           m.result_team_2 AS goals_for,
           m.result_team_1 AS goals_against
    FROM matches m
  ) r
  GROUP BY team
  ORDER BY points DESC, SUM(r.goals_for) - SUM(r.goals_against) DESC, goals_for DESC
) r
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) v
ORDER BY position
```

Output:

```
team    points  goals_for   goals_against   position
TEAM2   3       9           2               1
TEAM3   1       0           0               2
TEAM4   1       0           0               3
TEAM1   0       2           9               4
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rRBvEVQLDpmfHKMqFbK1DY/4)

This query relies on MySQL 8+ as it uses CTEs and the `ROW_NUMBER()` function (for the final ranking):

```
WITH teams AS (
  SELECT team1 AS team FROM matches
  UNION
  SELECT team2 FROM matches
),
results AS (
  SELECT t.team,
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.team1 = t.team AND m.result_team_1 > m.result_team_2 THEN 3
                  WHEN m.team2 = t.team AND m.result_team_2 > m.result_team_1 THEN 3
                  WHEN (m.team1 = t.team OR m.team2 = t.team) AND m.result_team_1 = m.result_team_2 THEN 1
                  ELSE 0 END) AS points,
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.team1 = t.team THEN m.result_team_1
                  ELSE m.result_team_2 END) AS goals_for,
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.team1 = t.team THEN m.result_team_2
                  ELSE m.result_team_1 END) AS goals_against
  FROM teams t
  JOIN matches m ON m.team1 = t.team OR m.team2 = t.team
  GROUP BY t.team)
SELECT t.team, r.points, r.goals_for, r.goals_against, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY r.points DESC, r.goals_for - r.goals_against DESC, r.goals_for DESC) AS position
FROM teams t
JOIN results r ON r.team = t.team
ORDER BY position
```

Output:

```
team    points  goals_for   goals_against   position
TEAM2   3       9           2               1
TEAM3   1       0           0               2
TEAM4   1       0           0               3
TEAM1   0       2           9               4
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rRBvEVQLDpmfHKMqFbK1DY/3)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `UNION ALL` to get results for each team. Then aggregate.

```
select
  team,
  sum(made) as goals_made,
  sum(got) as goals_got,
  sum(case when made > got then 3 when made = got then 1 else 0 end) as points
from
(
  select team1 as team, result_team_1 as made, result_team_2 as got from matches
  union all
  select team2 as team, result_team_2 as made, result_team_1 as got from matches
) team_results
group by team
order by points;
```

Replace `order by points` with what you consider appropriate. As of MySQL 8 you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to number the positions.